# Finding rank and determinant of following system of equations.

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

How to find the rank and determinant of following system of equations:

$$ c_{11}x_1^2+c_{12}x_2^2 + c_{13}x_1x_2+ c_{14}x_1+c_{15}x_2= C_1$$
$$ c_{21}x_1^2+c_{22}x_2^2 + c_{23}x_1x_2+ c_{24}x_1+c_{25}x_2= C_2$$
$$ c_{31}x_1^2+c_{32}x_2^2 + c_{33}x_1x_2+ c_{34}x_1+c_{35}x_2= C_3$$

I need to find the Determinant and rank of the matrix $(x_{ij})$. Please help

Comment: The coefficients are generic coefficients. What do you want to say?

Comment: when the term $X_1$ and $x_2$ are absent, it can be solved by taking $Z_1=x_1^2$, and so on,  but here $x_1$ and $x_2$ are prsent

Comment: Sure, but as they are given in the post, they're just indeterminates. Is there any context, hypotheses, &c.?

Comment: Ok, I need to find the resultant of 2 polynomials under some constraints.

Comment: which after substituting the root looks like this. Is there any software to solve these kind of problems/

Comment: There are software for calculating resultants, but I think you should post the real problem.